# inequality related to square the sum of any two sides of a triangle with respect to square of other side

Tags: geometry, triangles

Consider a,b,c are three side of a triangle. Now we need to find the relation between square the them sum of any two side of triangle with respect to third side.

**My approach**

As we know that the sum of any two sides of triangle will always be greater then the third side i.e

> $(a+b)>c $
>
> $(b+c)>a$
>
> $(a+c)>b$

Take square on both side then

> $a^2+b^2+2ab>c^2$
>
> $ c^2+b^2+2bc>a^2$
>
> $a^2+c^2+2ac>b^2$

Add last three equations

> $2a^2+2b^2+2c^2-a^2-b^2-c^2>-2(ab+bc+ac)$
>
> $a^2+b^2+c^2>-2(ab+bc+ac)$

Edited :
Corrected equation
But the correct answer is this $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 < 2(ab + bc + ca)$

What  am I doing wrong?Please guide.

Comment: Why not try your approach with inequalities like $a-c>-b$?  This is just another form of your initial inequality.

Comment: But what do you want to prove? That $a^2+b^2+c^2\geq2(ab+bc+ac)$?

Comment: @Dr.Mathva I want to prove this a2+b2+c2>2(ab+bc+ac)

Comment: @MichaelBurr I will try this approach as well, but what is wrong with my approch?

Comment: But, @Thinker, the inequality $2(ab+bc+ac)\geq a^2+b^2+c^2$ you want to prove is trivial from your last step

Comment: @Dr.Mathva I have updated the question. I am solving one question posted on this link https://www.askiitians.com/revision-notes/maths/quadratic-equations/solved-examples.html But the result they have used is different from what I am getting. Please refer Illustration 2 in the mentioned link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repeat your reasoning starting with this form of triangular inequalities:
$$
|a-b|<c,\quad |b-c|<a,\quad |c-a|<b,
$$
that is:
$$
(a-b)^2<c^2,\quad (b-c)^2<a^2,\quad (c-a)^2<b^2.
$$

Comment: Yes this triangular inequalities is providing the correct result. But I still have one doubt left . What is wrong with my approach. triangle holds a property that sum of any two side is always greater then third side. Why reasoning based on this property is giving unexpected result?

Comment: Your approach is fine, but leads to a trivial result, as you have on the right hand side a negative quantity and on the left hand side a positive quantity.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality you attained is **trivial** as the lengths of sides of a triangle **can't be negative or zero**. In fact the correct answer comes from$$(a-b)^2+(a-c)^2+(b-c)^2< c^2+b^2+a^2$$which is a direct outcome of **triangle inequality** you mentioned above (how?).

Comment: My reasoning was based on  the property that "The sum of the lengths of any two sides of a triangle is greater than the length of the third side. Similarly, the difference between the lengths of any two sides of a triangle is less than the length of the third side". But I understand that it is proving something that is not possible in as a,b, all will be greated than zero. But question is why?